# How do you setup a proxy for Jmeter's proxy server?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I would like to use Jmeter's proxy server to capture data into a thread group.

The problem is, I am currently behind a proxy and to access my target page, i need to tell jmeter's proxy server to forward all requests to that proxy!

Is this possible with jmeter? The documentation or the UI do not mention anything of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See the getting started manual: http://www.ingrid.org/jajakarta/jmeter/1.7/docs/usermanual/get-started.html

And here's a tutorial: http://www.testingminded.com/2010/04/running-jmeter-tests-from-behind-proxy.html

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the getting started link.